# MVC, how view should be accessed from controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm just learning MVC so you could find my question rather strange...

My Controller have access to different shared objects through Container object passed to Controller's constructor. To access shared objects I should do $this->container->db to access Database adapter or $this->container->memcache to access Memcached adapter. I want to know **should I put View object into Container with shared objects or no**?

From one side it is really comfortable to take view from this container, but this way I couldn't create multiple Views instances (for example, every time I'm calling Controller's method from View I should have one more View instance). What is the solution? How should I pass View object into Controller and/or how should I create new View instances from Controller?

Thank you!

Comment: what is that container thing?

Comment: ...and db adapter? controllers should imho work with models, not db or its adapters... models should be obtained from db by themselves or some repository delegate

Comment: why do you call controller method from view? Is it not against the separation between MVC?

Comment: @Gregoire, yes, I'm calling Controller method from view when I want to reuse some html returned by other controller methods. Probably, I should use some kind of Helpers to do it, but I don't know too much about helpers yet :)

Comment: @Gabriel Ščerbák, yeah It's a really bad example, sorry. Forget db adapter  (or course I'm using it only at Model). But I'm still using Config object (and I'm also accessing it through Container object).

Here is really sample Container object http://twittee.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, maybe try implementing caching for static parts. IMHO try inserting cacher object (through DI) to controller, and let that object decide if you want to send cached partial view or instantiate a new one. If you want to cache data from db, use the same pattern from controller towards models, so whenever in a controller you need models, ask db cacher object (same DI principle). Is it clear enough?

Comment: Gabriel Ščerbák, really, sorry for taking so much time. Your answers are really good.

Comment: no problem, but stay focused on the architecture, not concrete implementations, I am not expert, so look out for other implementations, many frameworks do it differently and MVC isn't good for everything (look at GUI frameworks, they have mostly component based structure).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that DI experience, do it on views as well, but I don't know if it really helps you anyway. Never call controller methods from views. Instead write some partial view methods and call them from views, which define the page layout (something similar to what Rails does).
IMHO if you want to get on MVC gradually, start from core principles and iteratively get to details, but don't learn architectural/design pattern as MVC by parts - architecture, design, the whole matters:)

Comment: What if I'd like to use some cached parts of HTML in my view? I have three ways - call controller method, call model method, call cacher method. Calling cacher method means passing some kind of key to it, but both cacher and view don't know anything about keys (but model and controller knows). Calling model method means that we should interact with View object from Model (I don't really know consider it bad or good).

Comment: Saying "cached parts" I meant partial HTML caching.